# Agrupar Últimos Ida Retornados pelo Insert no banco

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Nesse Script a baixo eu faço um laço onde dentro dele realizo insert no banco.
ao final de cada insert ele me retorna o ID da linha gravado no banco peça variavel (.$sql->insert_id .) até aqui tudo OK

```
if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {

foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $key => $value) {    
echo 'nome='.$nome = mysql_real_escape_string($value);  // data da saida
echo 'id='.$id_produtos2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id_produtos'][$key]); 
echo 'valor='.$valor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['valor'][$key]);

$bd = new MySQLiConnection();                                                                                                           
$sql = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTOcotacao(chave,id_transfer,id_empresa,para2,tipo,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");   // Atribui valores às variáveis da consulta
$sql->bind_param('isssss', $chave,$id_transfer,$id_empresa,$subcli,$off,$status,); 
if($sql->execute()){
print 'ID da linha gravado : ' .$sql->insert_id .'<br />';
echo $id_retornado = $sql->insert_id; 
}else{
die('Error : ('. $bd->errno .') '. $bd->error);
}
$sql->close();
```

- Meu problema é... em um loop de 3 , em cada insert, retornando um id novo
  como grava-los em uma variável, todos os ids que me retornaram

  ```
    Segue a logica
    3x Loop{

    Insert 
    retorno id 1 ...

   }

    $todos_ids_retornados = "1,2,3" ; // Isso que eu quero fazer e não sei como
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do laço de repetição salve os `id's` em um array utilizando o [array_push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php).

```
if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {

    $cotacao_id = []; //adicione esta linha
    foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $key => $value) {

        if ($sql->execute()) {
            array_push($cotacao_id, $sql->insert_id); //adicione esta linha
        } else {
            die('Error : (' . $bd->errno . ') ' . $bd->error);
        }
        $sql->close();
    }
}
```

Depois basta percorrer o array `$cotacao_id` com outro `foreach`.

```
foreach ($cotacao_id as $id) {
    //sua logica aqui
}
```